# ADO.NET is looking for a DbProvider which I don't want to use

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have a project using SqlServerCe.3.5 with EntityFramework 6. I want to change the database to PostgreSQL so I changed the configuration

From:

```
<entityFramework>
   <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.Legacy.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy" />
   </providers>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
       <parameters>
           <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
       </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1Container" connectionString="Data Source=<.. DB.sdf ...>" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 3.5" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

To:

```
<entityFramework>
   <providers>
       <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1Container" connectionString="Server=localhost;<...>" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

When I run my software with the new config file I got the following error:

```
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
var latestMigration = migrator.GetLocalMigrations().Last();
var charPos = latestMigration.IndexOf("_");
var migrationName = latestMigration.Substring(charPos + 1, latestMigration.Length - charPos - 1);
migrator.Update(migrationName);  // <<< it crashes here!!
```

Exception:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details. 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable'1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable'1 sourceFilePaths)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable'1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable'1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable'1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable'1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer'2& cachedCTypeFunction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable'1 xmlReaders)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable'1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable'1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at DAL.Session.Init() in <...>

I got this error message but my PostgreSQL database is created with all the tables defined in my CodeFirst EntityFramework.

In the `machine.config` there is no SqlServerCe nor Npgsql defined.

Is it possible that somewhere hidden there is a settings I don't see? I made a text search on all config and project files and I don't see any possible reason.

Comment: Does your code rely on the `System.Data.SqlCe` namespace anywhere?

Comment: No, I even removed the reference of `SqlServerCe` and I can build.

Comment: @doodoroma check again. SQL Server CE is a *very* specialized database and the 3.5 version is *ancient*. The last version was 4.0 which was discontinued many years ago. It's not used as a default anywhere. If you get such a message it means you still use it.  Log the full exception including its call stack and check *where* that error occurs and what call started that call chain.

Comment: @doodoroma did you *debug* your code? Where does that error occur?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I debug and it seems to fail at migration state: 

```System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer```

Comment: Post the code and the exception, not part of the message. Why are you executing migrations if this is a new database though? Do you have any hard-coded references to SQL Server CE in the migration scripts?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the OP.

Comment: @Doodoroma did you check the migrations for any references to the *old* database? Why run migrations at all in a *new* database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The migration is a must at the beginning of the startup. with the old DB it was working if the tables were empty. How can I check that? I double checked my code and all references, there is no trace of SqlServerCe.3.5 I could see.

Comment: look in the EDMX for SQL CE reference in connection string

Comment: @magicandre1981 there is no edmx file. I had one at the beginning of the project though. I moved to Code First because the EDMX didn't support something (I don't remember) which was available in Code First.  I extracted the code and removed the edmx file. Is there any chance that my problem is a left over from this? What should I look for? There is no SQL CE in reference, settings, conifg

Comment: delete bin/obj folders to fully rebuild the solution. maybe there is was still  a reference to the old SQL CE in the files and they were not updated during build. But **System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems** still looks EDMX related loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION! (For those who by any chance get into the same problem )

I ended up removing the migration completely and I rebuilt from scratch. I had used `Enable-Migrations` which was somehow linked to the current configuration. When I enable migration now, it was running without any problem.